# Calling a SQL Server View from EF 4.1 context object

Tags: entity-framework, entity

Has anyone had experience with calling a view using EF 4.1 DBContext object? If so could you provide an example. Also will this map to a POCO like a table does?

Thanks much,
Derek

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be used just like a regular table - POCO with name of the view as the table.

Answer (score 0):

I have called Oracle Views using EF 4. There is one requirement to add views to edmx and that is that you need to make a primary key column in it. One way to do that is to make a column containing row numbers and make it primary. Then it would be easily added to edmx.

As far as the last part of your question is concerned, Yes they will be accessible just like other tables using dbcontext.

Hope it helps.

Comment: He is using DbContext which I believe is code first, that means no entity model(edmx). But you are right on the primary key part - you need to create a primary key on the POCO object.